# Akka Java create testprobe ref with path ?

Tags: java, testing, akka

i'm still a little new to testing with akka. In a system i'm building i'm doing something like

```
private void tellPublisherAboutUpdates(Map<String,Update> updates){ 
        if(updates.isEmpty()){
            getContext().actorSelection(ActorSelectionPath.UPDATE_PUBLISHER.path()).tell(new InfoMessage<Map<String,Update>>(updates), getSelf());
        }
    }
```

Now, my first thoughts were, using TestProbe, to create a test ref with the relevant path, but i'm not sure how to do this ?  If there's an alternative method that is better suited to testing these kind of interactions i'm also keen to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern I have used to solve this problem involves creating a forwarding actor such as the following:

```
**
 * Simple actor that takes another actor and forwards all messages to it.
 * Useful in unit testing for capturing and testing if a message was received.
 * Simply pass in an Akka JavaTestKit probe into the constructor, and all messages
 * that are sent to this actor are forwarded to the JavaTestKit probe
 * Ref: https://gist.github.com/jconwell/8153535
 */
public class ForwardingActor extends UntypedActor {
    final ActorRef target;
    public ForwardingActor(ActorRef target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        target.forward(msg, getContext());
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this to inject your probe reference:

```
JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit(actorSystem);
actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(ForwardingActor.class, probe.getRef()), "myActor");
```

This works ok when you want your actor to be a child of the current actor, or a top-level actor, but if your actor path refers to an actor nested within the hierarchy it can be a bit trickier. I made use of the ForwardingActor in combination with the ChildCreationActor (https://gist.github.com/jconwell/8154233) to solve this problem.

I found out about the above techqiue via this blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2014/01/02/akka-test-patterns-for-java.aspx

Comment: Yeah i've used this pattern a couple of times before. I was hoping there was something more idiomatic

Comment: thanks, this is the only way I know at present...i'd also be interested in any improvements on this approach